# How can I preserve the page numbers between a twoside and a oneside layout?

Tags: page-numbering, double-sided

I want to publish a document in both printed and electronic versions. I use `twoside,open=right` for the printed version and `oneside` for the electronic version.

Due to the empty pages which are inserted in the `twoside` layout, the page numbers are going to diverge between the two layouts (see example below). Is there a sensible way to keep the page numbers in sync?

Solutions I can think of:

- Insert empty pages in the `oneside` layout. [Maybe this could be done by using the `twoside` layout and shifting the type area back to the center (ugly).]
- Use another layout for the electronic version. What is the 'best practice'? Publish the electronic version (for use in PDF reader) with the `twoside` layout?

---

Here is a simple example demonstrating the issue (I use the KOMA classes, but the same thing happens with `book`). The twoside layout has 10 pages while the oneside layout has 9 pages.

```
\documentclass[twoside,open=right]{scrbook}
% \documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument
\Blindtext
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: it depends what you want to do. Apart from the possibilities you mention, another is to use `oneside` but define `\cleardoublepage` to set the page count to odd _without_ throwing a blank page.

Comment: Why use the different layouts when you want them to look the same? Is the main problem the headers/footers? If that's the case, it may be easier to adjust them rather than the layout.

Comment: @Werner The headers/footers are a minor issue, yes. But I would like the electronic/PDF version to have a centered type area instead of the left/right-shifted layout of the printed version.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In this case, I would rather prefer to have empty pages included in the `oneside` layout. Missing page numbers might confuse the readers.

Comment: I would either just use exactly the same layout, or give up page numbers being the same, apart from one/two side distinction ideally the electronic version shouldn't be set for A4 aspect ratio either....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you for your opinion. I'm curious: What page format / aspect ratio do you suggest for an electronic version? One that is compatible with (portrait) screen sizes? I always have my PDFs in A4 format in case somebody wants to print them..

Comment: @shark.dp I don't know: it's a changing world:-) there is something to be said for ebooks to be html rather than pdf based, so they naturally reflow to whatever sceen shape and orientation is available...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a KOMA-Script class you could set `twoside=semi` and use `scrlayer-scrpage` to change the header and footer to oneside-layout.

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi,open=right]{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\leftmark}
\cfoot{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\Blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If the only issue is that of blank pages, then you could redefine prepend some code to `\chapter` to achieve this (first suggested solution):

```
%\documentclass[twoside,open=right]{scrbook}
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \clearpage% Move to next page
  \ifodd\value{page}\else% If this page is not odd/even...
  \mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage% ...insert a blank page and move to next page
  \fi
  \oldchapter
}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument
\Blindtext
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```